# Azure B2C - Error message alerts for wrong field

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Ive implemented a single sign-in sign-up unified policy using a custom template.

When the user enters their credentials but the EMAIL is wrong a message is displayed. Your Password is incorrect. The same message is displayed when I enter the PASSWORD wrong. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lclr.png)

Can I customize this message?  How?

Comment: Not sure if you can customize but that's actually a good way of doing things. It makes it so that someone can't find out if a user has an account there. I.e. it blocks account enumeration.

Comment: This is not possible now at least from edit policy.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Azure AD B2C today.

I'd recommend you add an entry in the [Azure AD B2C UserVoice forum](http://aka.ms/aadb2cuv).